# configure c3p0 with eclipselink

Tags: java, jdbc, eclipselink, entitymanager, c3p0

I am using EclipseLink in my project. Due to some connection pool issue, I have to use c3p0 with EclipseLink. Is it possible to use both c3p0 and EclipseLink configuration both combined as follows,

```
<persistence-unit name="samplePU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <properties> 

        <property name="eclipselink.sessions-xml" value="META-INF/sessions.xml"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.session-name" value="xxx"/>

        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />


        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="100" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="0" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="0" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="100" />


        <!-- properties to fine tune logging -->
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.timestamp" value="true"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.thread" value="true"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.session" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: did you bother searching?

Comment: no not at all  @ScaryWombat.

Comment: well don't you think that would be a **great** start?

Comment: ok, @ScaryWombat. Can you opt me something

Comment: Eclipselink is jpa provider as hibernate, toplink and c3p0 is connection pool mechanism. So it is possible

Comment: EclipseLInk is not going to understand hibernate persistence properties.  See http://onpersistence.blogspot.com/2008/04/eclipselink-and-datasources.html on how to pass in a datasource to EclipseLink.